# Java: How does a call to the super class constructor inside of a child class constructor work?

Tags: java

I'm just trying to get my head around this.  Let's say I have the following constructor for the superclass Geometry:

```
public Geometry(double x, double y)
    {
        this.position = new Point(x,y);
        this.collisionMesh = new ArrayList<Point>();
        this.displayMesh = new ArrayList<Point>();
    }
```

Geometry has the members position, collisionMesh, and displayMesh, which all of its child classes will inherit.

Now, I have a child class, Particle.  Is the following a valid constructor:

```
public Particle(double x, double y)
{
   super(x,y);
   this.collisionMesh.add(this.position);
   ...
}
```

What I want to make sure of is this: the call to super(x,y) automatically instantiates my child object's ArrayLists and Point, so that I don't need to do so.

Also, on a deeper level, and assuming I can do this, what's really going on here?  It feels like I'm calling a constructor inside of a constructor.  What is it that gets constructed during the call to super, if the Particle object isn't done being constructed yet?

Comment: Google is your friend https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions which don't resemble much with reality. Hint: all of that is nicely and extensively documented.

Comment: "Constructor" is not very fortunate name. What is constructing (in sense of creating) object is `new` keyword. It creates object of type which appears after it like `new SomeClass`. Constructor is like method which *initialize* already created object to proper state (so it is like special method called by `new` operator, based on provided arguments).

Comment: Thank you, @Pshemo, that clarifies. To everyone else: admittedly, I could have done more research, but now I'm just having fun seeing how low the downvotes can go...

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky Which is really a bad idea. You see, people could actually decide to SPAM flag such a comment. It is one thing to put up a "bad question" ... but then go "hey, lets just keep it" for study purposes ... not a good idea. If you agree that you put up a bad question: then improve it or delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the object you need to call the constructors of the super class. It must be on the first line of your constructor. If you don't add that line java automatically calls the super class constructor without arguments (like there is an invsible super() ). This goes back to the class Object itself. This way when you construct an object you intentionally (or not if you don't write super()) call the constructors of all super classes.

If the super class doesn't have no arguments constructor you get a compile error in the subclass if you don't call the super constructor with proper arguments (because this cannot work automatically).

When you create a type Particle it first creates an Object, then extends that object to a Geometry and then to a Particle. I hope I explained it properly ;)